# Is there a text editor that previews LaTeX?

Tags: editors

Is there a text editor that previews what we written in LaTeX codes?

Comment: You may be looking for [LyX](https://www.lyx.org/).

Comment: Or emacs with AucTeX – it comes with [previewing functionality](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/preview-latex.html) (e.g. for maths).

Comment: Nearly every latex editor provides some preview capability.  Texstudio http://www.texstudio.org/ Texshop http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/ Gummi https://github.com/alexandervdm/gummi and bakoma http://www.bakoma-tex.com/ Of these bakoma has a WYSIWYG interface, but limited in its TeX options.

Answer (score 2):

I have made a [live preview plugin](http://zohooo.github.io/quadview) for [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com) editor. It will show the preview of current paragraph in the upper right corner of WinEdt. Furthermore it will update the preview automatically if current paragraph has been changed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One feature of TeXStudio is

> Live-updating inline preview for formulas and code segments